# Nodal voltage calculation

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

Although i should use mesh current to find the Vo, i try to apply nodal voltage at Vo. Eventually,i get the wrong answer. 
What is wrong with my calculation or concept?

Comment: Please don't make us read hieroglyphs. Lay your equations out in the body of the question, using the tex interpreter.

Comment: You need a node voltage at the 1ohm/ 2ohm/ 5A node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your terms for a current leaving the central node is \$\frac{v_0 - 40}{3}\$.

This assumes the 1 ohm and 2 ohm are connected in series, but they are not.

Two resistors are only in series if the exact same current must flow through both resistors.